# showing the current flowing through a capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the question "Show that the size of the current flowing through the capacitor, Ic is 6.16 A.

I am given the voltage of the circuit to be 48.0 v and the frequency to be 50.0 Hz however I am not sure what the equation is to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure what the equation is to show this

V/I is impedance where impedance in your specific question is the reactance of the capacitor. Reactance is: -

\$\dfrac{1}{2\pi f C}\$ where f is frequency and C is capacitance

So calculate reactance and divide it into the AC RMS voltage to get current: -

I (RMS) = \$\dfrac{Voltage}{Reactance}\$

Answer (score 2):

You have the frequency and voltage and want to determine the current thru a capacitor.

You are missing one degree of freedom.  The current can't be computed without more information, like the capacitance.